# Make subquery with like

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have the following two tables. How can I make a query where the table B variant_id matched in Table A combination?

```
TableA
product_id  combination     ean
1           952_4038        123456789
2           946_3989        101010101

TableB
variant_id  desc
4038        text1
3989        text2
```

Thanks!

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far. If you haven't tried anything, do that.

Comment: Is combination a fixed format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*
FROM    TableA a
        INNER JOIN TableB b
            ON a.combination LIKE CONCAT('%', b.variant_ID)
```

This query is terribly slow on large databases. Consider normalizing your table properly.

My Proposed Table Schema:

TableA

- ProductID (1)
- IntColumn (952)
- Combination (4038)
- Ean (123456789)

TableB

- Combination (4038)
- DescColumn (text) [*don't use reserved keyword*]

make sure to have indexes on the linking fields.

---

*Followup question: which table is the main table and the dependent table?*